# bug on show reapeted background on landscape and portrait

Tags: android, android-layout

bg_repeat.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/bg_pattern"
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

bg_pattern.jpg:
[image: bg_pattern.jpg]
if i launch app in portrait mode:
[image: portrait]
and output is okey.

and if launch app in landscape mode,sometimes output(in splashScreen BG and Main BG) is like:
[image: landscape]
and second problem in this mode(LandS): i change orientation to portrait,and press back button to close app,its refresh current activity(1,2,or even 4 time via each pressing Back btn)(refresh means go back to current activity from current! )

whats wrong? is this a bug?(each two question).
bytheway its my splashScreen.java code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
private int _splashTime = 2000;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread(){
       @Override
       public void run(){
         Intent mainMenu = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, NextAct.class);
         SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainMenu);
         SplashScreen.this.finish();
         overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
       }
    }, _splashTime);
 }
}
```

after all i said,i use customTheme.
this is manifest xml code:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SplashScreen">
```

and this is part of styles.xml code:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_repeat</item>
</style>
```

but don't test this new app,that has problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not repeating background is a known bug which was partially fixed in ICS and fully in JB. There's a workaround, you have to wrap bitmap in layout and then set repeating in code in onCreate like this :

```
    parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
    Bitmap bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.bg_pattern);
    BitmapDrawable patternRepeat = new BitmapDrawable(bg);
    patternRepeat.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    patternRepeat.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    parent.setBackgroundDrawable(patternRepeat);
```

Comment: please see question again.so how can do your solution in this situation(updated question) ?